# After synchronizing my iPod nano 6G with banshee or rhythmbox, it appears empty

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee, ipod

I want to synchronize my music between Ubuntu 14.04 and my iPod Nano (6th gen).

I have read pretty much everything but am still blocked... I tried with Rhythmbox and with Banshee and I get the same behavior:

- The iPod is recognized
- I can drag and drop my playlist to the iPod (which apparently works, as there is a synchronization progress bar and as the iPod's screen also shows that synchro is ongoing)
- Apparently the synchro was successful, since I can play the music from the iPod (in Rhythmbox or Banshee)
- I eject my iPod and... it's like the music disappeared: the iPod pretends to be empty and, when I plug it back to the computer, it also appears empty in both Rhythmbox and Banshee

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. See my related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/934877/how-to-restore-ipod-database-messed-up-by-rhythmbox

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't like it if users use other software than iTunes to sync their iDevices.

Thus, they use a very specific directory and file naming system, which needs to be used, the iPod will ignore any files not matching the naming criteria.

However, there's a nice synching program called GtkPod, which implements this naming structure. You can install it from the software center or with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```

Now you can start GtkPod and manage your iPod from this software.

---

Source: My own experience

Comment: Thanks for that! GtkPod however keeps on crashing all the time. I will try again but if anyone has any other idea, I'd be happy to read about other options :-)

Comment: Try starting GtkPod from terminal and see the error message. This may help with debugging.

Comment: Does this really solve the problem? I'm under the impression that both GtkPod and Rhythmbox use the same underlying library: libgpod. See https://github.com/fadingred/libgpod

Comment: @sondra.kinsey is right. And for ipod Nano 6G libhashab is needed as well: https://github.com/Amoystyle/libhashab

Answer (score 1):

Having trouble finding the link, but pretty sure I found earlier that libgpod (the library most programs use to access your device) does not support the Nano 6G.  Found that out the hard way with the same symptoms.